# laravel passport auth code - asking to grant permissions, is it nessecarry?

Tags: php, laravel, security, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am looking for some clarification as for how exactly to proceed with Oauth auth code PKCE grant when it comes to authorizing my own SPA.

So I get this when I am redirected from my SPA to backend (after I log in of course):

[image]

Now I get this, makes sense if I want to login into my app with google or twitter for example.

But If I want to log in to the backend app to get the token with my SPA - is there a way to avoid that every time a user logs in? Does it make sense?

I would like to have it from user perspective like this:

- click login
- redirect to backend pretending to be SPA (visually)
- login
- go straight back to SPA without having to confirm that stuff

I just mainly want to understand the process for SPA. I assume and suspect that what I want is simply not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can :)

Create your own Passport client.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models;

class PassportClient extends \Laravel\Passport\Client
{
    /**
     * Determine if the client should skip the authorization prompt.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function skipsAuthorization()
    {
        // todo: add some checks, e.g. $this->name === 'spa-client'
        return true;
    }
}
```

And update your `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`.

```php
public function boot()
{
    // ...

    Passport::useClientModel(PassportClient::class);
}
```

Comment: Hey Ron :) It's been a while :D Thanks! Just out of pure curiosity, I assume if I  control the backend as well as the front end this is not gonna be a security risk right?

Comment: In your case, it does not matter. Normally, the user gets a screen with `SPA want to use your personal information`, but if you control both client and auth server, it does not really matter. You already know that information :) P.s. nice to see you make such great progress.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was hoping for. Yeah, makes sense, I own that so it is redundant to ask about something I fully control anyway. Thank you, for your kind words :) I am trying to learn as much as I can while getting this MVP to a live-ready state. Thanks again for all the help. If I will put that whole process on my blog I can refer you if you want.

Comment: I would be honored. You do make me curious to that blog :)

Comment: Hah, currently it's a bit slow and I need to move it to another hosting or it will go down. I am working also apart from this project on moving my blog and doing new design => robertkabat.com

Comment: I will pick up the pace though!

Comment: Wauw, great job man! Can't wait to read more!

Comment: Finally had some time to do it, took maybe 3 minutes and worked like a charm!